# Delay job pause/resume job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

Is it possible to pause/resume job?

For example i want to suspend my `Delayed::Job.last` last job and than resume it.

My jobs uploading files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No It is not possible

Please read it

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/58

To suspend/delete your last job

```
# list all jobs
Delayed::Job.all
# find a job by id
job = Delayed::Job.find(params[:id]) || Delayed::Job.last
# delete it
job.delete
```

Then start it

Better you can enqueue it

```
my_job = MyJob.new(User.send_data) #some user  model method send_data
job = Delayed::Job.enqueue(my_job, 0, 1.hour.from_now)
job.name
# => "MyJob-User-1"
job.handler
```

Comment: i read it,it dated  2010.. thought maybe someone did it already